# Test if variable has type "list of tuples"

Tags: python

How can I check if a variable is a list of tuples?

**isinstance** only reveals if a variable is a list or a tuple, but I don't know how to check nested structures.

Comment: Since Python is dynamically typed you will have to check every element of the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a combination of `all` and `instanceof`:

```
>>> a = [(1,2),(3,5)]
>>> all(isinstance(item, tuple) for item in a)
True
>>> b = [(1,2),(3,5), "string"]
>>> all(isinstance(item, tuple) for item in b)
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `all`

```
>>> lit=[(1,),(2,),(3,)]
>>> lin=[(1,),(2,),(3,),4]

>>> all(isinstance(e,tuple) for e in lit)  
True
>>> all(isinstance(e,tuple) for e in lin)  
False
```

You can also negate a lambda in filter both to test and to find the elements that are not tuples:

```
>>> filter(lambda e: not isinstance(e, tuple), lit)
[]
>>> filter(lambda e: not isinstance(e, tuple), lin)
[4]
```

Or use a list comprehension to find the index of the non tuple:

```
>>> [i for i, e in enumerate(lit) if not isinstance(e, tuple)]
[]
>>> [i for i, e in enumerate(lin) if not isinstance(e, tuple)]
[3]
```

If you use `filter` or a list comprehension, an empty list is also 'falsy' so that can both be a test and a result if you are looking for the actual elements that are not tuples.